# Angular 4 : Is it possible to force a link to open an URL in a different browser?

Tags: angular, browser

In angular 4 I have opened a website in the Chrome Browser
and I want to open a link in a window in Firefox. Is this possible?

Comment: That would be awful.

Answer (score 1):

There is now way to do something like this. The Browser is a sandbox which has certain restrictions.

It would be a **major threat to security**  (and usability) if you could access the users' OS like this and start a different application. Furthermore there is *luckily* no way to check which applications a user has installed through your Browser.

You can determine which Browser the User is (probably) using - in JavaScript and PHP for instance and conditionally display content depending on this e.g. recommend opening the website within another Browser.

Examples:

http://php.net/manual/de/function.get-browser.php

[How to detect Safari, Chrome, IE, Firefox and Opera browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847580/how-to-detect-safari-chrome-ie-firefox-and-opera-browser)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not, you are sandboxed in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

What you might do is check the user's browser and give them a warning to use another browser, or even a link to the other browser's download page.

Use `navigator.userAgent` to check if it's Firefox (or any other).

```
if (!~navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Firefox')) {
     // not Firefox, show the message.
}
```